Keybinds not working after clicking button even after the focus is set to false on the button
the key bind stops working whenever you press the test button but, if you move the "new Gameloop" line outside of the button it works fine
I tried making the button unfocusable as I thought it was a focus issue even tho keybindings are supposed to work even with out primary focus but that didn't work
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Main {
    public static JFrame force = new JFrame();
    public static Rectangle player = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        force.setUndecorated(true);
        force.setLayout(null);
        force.setFocusable(true);
        force.setSize(1000,1000);
        // only using right for this example
        Rightmove right = new Rightmove();
        InputMap in =  force.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('d'),"right");
        ActionMap am = force.getRootPane().getActionMap();
        am.put("right",right);
        JButton test = new JButton("test");
        test.setFocusable(false);
        force.add(test);
        test.setBounds(100,100,100,50);
        test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Gameloop();
            }
        });
        force.setVisible(true);
    }
    static class Rightmove extends AbstractAction{
        public Rightmove() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            player.x += 4;
        }
    }
    private static class Gameloop{
        public Gameloop(){
            while (true){
                force.requestFocus();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1000,1000,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
                g.drawRect(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height);
                g = force.getGraphics();
                g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
            }
        }
    }
}



Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is first create a JFrame and add your KeyBinding to the frame. Get that working. Then add your button to the frame and get that working. The idea is to simplify the code. You have posted way too much code for us to look at.  2) The over usage of static variables indicates an improper design. 3) Class names should start with an upper case character. 4) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java conventions.


@camickr I changed it to a minimal reproducible example, sorry I don't ask about code much as I try to solve it myself, so I didn't think to do that.

Your code breaks Swing threading rules. Why not use a Swing Timer for the game loop instead of a while (true) loop?

@HovercraftFullOfEels changing to that worked thatnks, I didn’t know they existed so I didn't use them
